# Custom MapReduce Input Format - Can't Find Constructor

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a custom InputFormat for Hadoop 0.20.2 and am running into a NoSuchMethodException I can't get rid of.  I started with:

```
public class ConnectionInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Connection> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Connection> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new ConnectionRecordReader();
    }
}
```

I got this error when running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: testingground.TestInputJob$ConnectionInputFormat.<init>()
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:882)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
at testingground.TestInputJob.run(TestInputJob.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at testingground.TestInputJob.main(TestInputJob.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: testingground.TestInputJob$ConnectionInputFormat.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
... 8 more
Java Result: 1
```

After getting the error inititially and researching online, I thought it might be that I didn't have a zero-argument constructor, so I added one:

```
public class ConnectionInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Connection> {

    public ConnectionInputFormat() {
        System.out.println("NetflowInputFormat Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Connection> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new ConnectionRecordReader();
    }
}
```

That didn't work either, so I added a second constructor that took in any number of objects:

```
public class ConnectionInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Connection> {

    public ConnectionInputFormat() {
        System.out.println("NetflowInputFormat Constructor");
    }

    public ConnectionInputFormat(Object... o) {
        System.out.println("NetflowInputFormat Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Connection> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new ConnectionRecordReader();
    }
}
```

Still getting the same error, and have been so far unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Full current source: http://pastebin.com/2XyW5ZSS

Comment: Just remove your constructor, there is no need to have a constructor in your input format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ConnectionInputFormat class should be static. Non-static nested classes have an implied 'this' added to every constructor. Thus, your no-arg constructor actually has an invisible argument unless the class is declared static.

Comment: Came to a similar conclusion after some hard debugging last night.  The "this" being sent to the constructor was the parent class (TestInputJob).  The class was then comparing the number of parameters in constructors of "this" or TestInputJob (there are none) to the number of parameters in constructors in the nested class ConnectionInputFormat.  Since they are obviously different, it was failing.

Comment: @BugsPray: That's what I was trying to say. Your wording is better.